# Detecting when the user reached the left or the right screen edge of the device

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and I would like to call a method when the gesture reaches the left or the right screen edge.

I thought about getting the location and compare it with the location of the edges.

Is there a better way? If not, instead of choosing myself the coordinates where an edge starts, what are the standard ones? Is it something like 10%? More? Less?

Comment: You can use EdgeGestureRecognizer available from iOS 8. It would be easy for you.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer

Comment: not really. This gesture would be triggered only if I start from the edges. I need to be able to start the pan gesture anywhere on the screen, eventually reach an edge and eventually leave this edge, still panning.

Comment: why not get the screen: width then look into touchesBegan, and get the current CGPoint (where the user touches). set ur range, when the x reaches a "x" value, then fire an action.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work when detecting if the user is getting close to left/right edge of the screen.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first as UITouch!{
        let currentPoint = floor(touch.locationInView(self.view).x)
        //print("touched point \(currentPoint) x")
        edgeReach(currentPoint)
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first as UITouch! {
        let currentPoint = floor(touch.locationInView(self.view).x)
        //print("moved to point \(currentPoint) x")
        edgeReach(currentPoint)
    }
}

func edgeReach(locationX: CGFloat) {
    if locationX >= 364 {
        print("closer to right edge")
    }
    if locationX <= 50{
        print("close to left edge")
    }
}
```

If you incorporate this into your current UIPanGestureRecognizer as well.

Comment: Yes that's what I had in mind, just wondering if there was a better way to do it.